# Can I log dual received if I received training from a CFI and I sit in the back seat?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, logging

> (h) Logging training time.
>
> 1. **A person may log training time when that person receives
>    training from an authorized instructor in an aircraft**, full flight
>    simulator, flight training device, or aviation training device.
> 2. The training time must be logged in a logbook and must:
>
>    (i) Be endorsed in a legible manner by the authorized instructor; and
>
>    (ii) Include a description of the training given, the length of the
>    training lesson, and the authorized instructor's signature,
>    certificate number, and certificate expiration date.

([14 CFR § 61.51](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-A/section-61.51))

Consider a 4-seat airplane with flight controls for the front seats only.  If there are two students on one flight and they go up with a CFI and neither one touches the flight controls can they both log the instruction time?  Assume the CFI takes off and shows the students how to conduct various maneuvers and how to track an ILS glide slope. Can the student in the back log training time since they received training from a CFI in an airplane? I sent off a request for legal interpretation but they said it could take up to four months to get a response.

Comment: What kind of training time do you mean? Do you mean flying hours?

Comment: If sitting in a passenger seat qualified as experience the world would be full of terrible pilots.

Comment: Would you add up the dual received column in your log book and count it as pilot time for the purpose of hitting the PPL hour minimums?

Comment: 61.51 (c)Logging of pilot time. The pilot time described in this section may be used to:
(1) Apply for a certificate or rating issued under this part or a privilege authorized under this part. So PIC, SIC, instrument time, training time, NVG. Some call training time dual received but that is wrong it is "training time". 61.51 (h) states that training time is time obtained from instruction in an aircraft.

Comment: I would add up this training time for the purposes of obtaining a certificate.

Comment: If that worked, there would be an awful lot of people getting most of their dual instruction credit sitting in the back to save big bucks.  You're just an observer, not a student when you sit in the back.

Comment: @James I think the issue is where does the pilot receiving the training have to be sitting in order for it to be credited as aeronautical experience (i.e. flight training). Is the back seat ok or does the person have to be at a "pilot station."

Comment: It just say to log training time I have to be in an aircraft. The instructor has to be at the flight controls

Comment: By your reasoning, which seems to be contrary to the logic relied upon in the Williams' FAA Interpretation (linked in my answer below), *training time* (flight instruction) could then  be received  and logged for credit in accordance with 61.51 by 5 students simultaneously in a Cessna 210: the CFI occupying one pilot station, a student in the other pilot station and the other 4 students sitting in the 4 rear passenger seats. I guess anything is possible,  but I don't think the FARs would permit that.

Comment: @James -- you'd be lucky if you got a legal interpretation 4 months after your submission, I think the average is at least double that.  To get a sense of this, peruse the interpretations available here -- https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/ .  Note also the content indicating that the FAA has tightened their policy and will now only issue interpretations on matters "that present a novel or legally significant issue" -- if they consider your request too trivial, they'll just ignore it --

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, the FAA Legal interpretation [Williams 2018 Legal Interpretation](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/Data/interps/2018/Williams_2018_Legal_Interpretation.pdf), makes a compelling argument that a person receiving flight training must occupy a pilot station.  The pertinent portion of this (multi-question) legal interpretation states that a Flight Instructor must occupy a pilot station and it also states that the other pilot station is for the student. Read in full context, it seems fairly clear to me that the pilot receiving the flight training must be in a pilot station to credit the flight time as instruction received.

However, getting a direct FAA legal interpretation for your specific point would provide an unambiguous answer to your question.

The image below is a *pertinent portion* of the linked Williams 2018 Legal Interpretation. Although the interpretation specifies the requirement that the instructor must occupy a pilot station, its corollary seems reasonably clear to also apply to the person receiving the flight instruction.

[image]

Comment: Which is pretty much what common sense would overwhelmingly suggest.

Comment: I wonder if you could record it as “ground” instruction.

Comment: It would be funny to see a plane with more than two pilot stations.

Comment: @Joshua - Yes some do look funny: https://images.app.goo.gl/5CGZ6y37karfNdEu6